# Noise near font after adding text via ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert

I put text on image and have some noise. How I can fix it?
Image magick options:

```
[
                currentImage,
                "-font", "Micra-Bold",
                "-pointsize", "40",
                "-strokewidth", "1",
                "-stroke", "black",
                "-fill", "white",
                "-gravity", "North",
                "-annotate", "+0+10", req.body.memData.actNumber,
                "-gravity", "South",
                "-pointsize", "26",
                "-annotate", "+0+10", req.body.memData.actText,
                ""+memsPath+tempName+".jpg"
            ];
```

and my image [image]

Answer (score 1):

The noise may be JPEG artifacts.  Try using a higher quality (your image has quality 70 according to "identify -verbose"). So, try

```
"-quality", "92",
```

for example.